# Database in DMZ and SMTP relay

Tags: email, smtp, dmz

I have an application that talks with a database in the DMZ. There is a firewall between the apps and the db but our developer thought that they require a mail notification that is triggered from the database through some specific SQL stored requests. I hate it.

And now, it is required to have the db to have a direct access to the SMTP server which is really on the RED zone (needless to say that it is not secure). I would like to ask some hints regarding the best practice and architecture on this.

Comment: This might be too broad to answer. Why is it a problem for the DB to initiate connections out to a trusted server? What are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @schroeder really sorry for the delay. Actually, the SMTP server is supposed to be outside the trusted zone, since it is just a relay on the perimeter zone, means that it has a direct internet access and so on. The DB in the other hand is totally in the "inside" network of the DMZ. I thought that It won't be great to have some kind of direct connection even if it is initiated from the DB. But I am not sure!